# Mirage (Cloudflare) causes GMaps not to display correctly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare with my site, with Mirage enabled.
This causes Google Maps not to display correctly on mobile. The map itself appears, but is distorted. Switching Mirage off fixes this (but I'd like to have it on for its other benefits). Does anyone know the solution to this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the Page Rules tab of CloudFlare you can exclude certain scripts or images from performance functionality.

By adding a Page Rule for which ever resources are being broken by Mirage, you can make sure CloudFlare won't compress and optimise images that you don't want optimised.

The Page Rules tab is in your CloudFlare dashboard:

[image: CloudFlare Page Rules tab]

Here is [a complete guide on using CloudFlare's Page Rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-).

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is related to the default zoom on the Gmap. The Gmaps I have are on a variety of pages, so page rules won't work. I've read the guide but I can't see how to exclude SCRIPTS from performance functionality, can you please advise (I'm using GMaps API via Jquery)